# Automatically assign keyboard hotkey to application at startup?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

### Background

My laptop keyboard is busted, so I use a USB keyboard. This keyboard has no designated calculator hotkey (such as Fn + Num Del on my laptop keyboard), so I like to assign my own (Ctrl + Num Del) under Start Menu → Calculator → Properties → Shortcut key. However, now and again (I believe on system reboot, but I haven’t checked for certain) this shortcut key is reset and I have to reassign it, which I end up doing this several times a week, which gets tiresome.

### The Question

Is there a way to automate this process so that the desired keyboard hotkey is automatically assigned, either via an app that runs at startup, or a batch file (which could then be scheduled to run at startup), etc.?

Please bear in mind I am no expert and have zero programming/coding/CMD knowledge, which is why I ask here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free and open source software called `Clavier+`. It allows you to create new keyboard shortcuts.

You can install it from here. [http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php].

Here is a screenshot of the application with keyboard shortcut creation.

[image: custom keyboard shortcut application]

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I’m looking for. Thanks.